# Seeking a Model to Extrapolate Locate Fees for Short Selling in Absence of Historical Data

Tags: programming, equities, extrapolation

I'm in the process of developing an automated stock trading algorithm, with short selling being a significant part of the strategy. A key factor in deciding whether to short a stock is the associated "locate fee". This fee can vary significantly across stocks and over time.

While I understand that the most accurate way to predict these fees would be through historical data, I currently don't have access to a comprehensive database of past locate fees. As such, I'm looking for suggestions on constructing a mathematical or statistical model to extrapolate or estimate the locate fees based on other available stock attributes or market data.

Some considerations and information:

1. The trades are driven by a predictive model that provides an expected return for each trade.
2. I'm looking for a balance between maximizing the expected value of the model and maximizing the number of trades.
3. I have access to other stock data, including liquidity measures, trading volume, short interest, sector/industry classifications, etc.

Has anyone faced a similar challenge or can provide insights on how to approach this problem? Are there specific models, statistical techniques, or proxies that have proven effective in estimating locate fees in the absence of direct historical data?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about locate fees (a one-time upfront fee to locate the shares) as opposed to overnight borrow fees (a fee paid each night you hold the short position)? I ask because QuantRocket has historical borrow fee data back to 2018: https://www.quantrocket.com/data/?filter=stockloan Borrow fees are more common, while only certain brokers charge locate fees.

Comment: I am talking about locate fees. I pay something in the morning to borrow some shares and use it to short it intraday